# ExpressJS variable undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an ExpressJS app that when a user makes a `POST` request to a route, it should lookup the ID in the MongoDB using `req.params.formId`

I have some console.log statements tfor debugging and so I can see what info is being returned.

The route should lookup the ID passed and when it finds it, use the `req.body` data and also a field from the MongoDB document but this just seems to return as `undefined`

Here is the code for the route:

```
app.post("/api/v1/forms/:formId", (req, res) => {
    const { name, email, message } = req.body;
    console.log(req.body);

    Form.findById(req.params.formId, Form.recipient, err => {
      if (err) {
        res.send(err);
      } else {
        const formRecipient = Form.recipient;

        const newForm = {
          name,
          email,
          message,
          recipient: formRecipient
        };
        console.log(newForm);
        const mailer = new Mailer(newForm, contactFormTemplate(newForm));
        try {
          mailer.send();
          res.send(req.body);
        } catch (err) {
          res.send(err);
        }
      }
    });
  });
```

So an example, if I make a POST request to `localhost:5000/api/v1/forms/5ad90544883a6e34ec738c19` the console.log of `newForm` shows `{ name: ' Mr Tester',
  email: 'person@example.com',
  message: 'Hi there',
  recipient: undefined }`

The forms Mongoose schema has a field named `recipient`

Answer (score 0):

the correct way is to provide the fields you want to get as the second argument:

```
Form.findById(req.params.formId, 'recipient', (err, form) => {

   if (err) {
     // error handling code
   } else {
     const formRecipient = form.recipient;
   }
   ...
});
```

here's the **[`Docs`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#findbyid_findById)**